# How to create texture for sculpting from mesh

Tags: texturing, sculpting

I've made this mesh that i want to use as a texture for sculpting, how should I do this?[image]
would creating a normal map of it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may render the *AO* of your sculpt and use it as an *alpha texture* for sculpting. Though I don't think it's a perfect method it gives a decent result.
[image]

I've quickly sculped some rocks to show you an example.
[image]

First remove all the lamps from your scene. Then add a *material* to your sculpt and set its ***specularity*** to ***0.000***
[image]

Select your *camera* and set its type to ***Ortographic***. Set the *Ortographic Scale* to fit the sculpt borders as you want.
[image]

Go to ***World*** header, set the ***Horizon Color*** to *black*. Check the ***Ambient Occlusion*** checkbox (*Add*, *Factor 1.000*). In *Gather* panel choose the ***Raytrace*** and set the ***Samples*** to desired amount (the more samples, the more detailed alpha texture for sculpting'll be). ***Render, then save rendered image.***
[image]

Now load your rendered image as an *alpha texture* in the *Texture* panel of the ***Sculpt Mode***.
[image]

I used the ***Stencil*** mapping type with a harsh curve type to sculpt, but you may experiment with it.
[image]

***NOTE:*** You may try to ***bake*** the *AO* (from the sculpt to a flat plane [*selected to active*]), save the result and then use it as the alpha mask for sculpting. I haven't tried this method though.

Comment: Thanks, this may be somewhat unrelated, but how did you make the high poly plane to sculpt on (subdividing a square turns it into a circle for me)?

Comment: I just subdivided the plane in *Edit Mode* many times to create a dense geometry and added a *Subsurf Modifier* with 3 subdivisions.